# Indexar pagina do site como tópicos no google

Tags: google, seo, sitemap

Olá, gostaria de saber como se faz para otimizar os links do site de maneira que seja exibidos por tópicos como na imagem? 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

De que maneira posso aplicar no desenvolvimento do site em SEO
Não o nome dessa técnica, parece que é onebox ou algo semelhante

por favor me ajudem!

Comment: Você utiliza o google analytics? Coloquei o google analytics em um site e dividi a pagina inicial em <article> e <section> e ele funcionou aparece no google conforme a imagem.

Comment: Ainda não uso,  poderia me dar um norte ou algum tutorial para eu iniciar rsrs

Comment: https://analytics.google.com/

Answer (score 2):

O nome disso é "sitelinks".

Quem determina o que e como será exibido na página de resultado do google é o próprio mecanismo do mesmo. Você não pode determinar quais links devem aparecer. Pode apenas pedir a remoção de um link ou outro, ou todos.

Para que o mecanismo do google encontre os links e determine o que é mais relevante, obviamente o site deve possuir uma boa semântica de acordo com as recomendações SEO.

Exemplo, categorias devem estar dentro das tags `ul li`

```
<ul>
<li>foo 1</li>
<li>foo 2</li>
<li>foo 3</li>
</ul>
```

Não tem muito segredo, basta seguir as normas recomendadas como:

- Evitar conteúdo pobre, por exemplo, páginas com pouco conteúdo.
- Possuir um menu principal com os links mais importantes do site.
- Evitar conteúdo duplicado. Aqui você deve prestar muita atenção a links canônicos (é outro assunto).
- Submissão do sitemaps
- Breadcumb
- Relevante quantidade de acessos.
- Descrição clara sobre a página.

Dentre outros diversos pontos.

O mais importante é provavelmente a quantidade de acessos. Mesmo um site mal feito com semântica ruim, porém, com muitos acessos, o sitelink é ativado pelo google.

O ponto mais difícil é conseguir uma boa e constante quantidade de acessos e o restante são meros detalhes que facilitam o mecanismo de busca a interpretar as páginas.

Primeiramente construa um site com bom conteúdo e boa semântica que o restante vai aparecendo "automaticamente".